# CSS animation glow effect around png image

Tags: html, css, animation

```css
.zuphologo {
 padding-top: 33%;
 padding-bottom: 2%;
}

.fx {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px 4px #fff;
  animation: glow 1.5s linear infinite alternate;

}

@keyframes glow{
  to {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 20px #fff;
  }
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col text-center zuphologo">
        <a href="google.co.uk">
          <img src="assets/img/logo.png" width="150" class="fx glowing purple">
        </a><br>
        <img src="assets/img/logoMyZupho.png" width="250" class="myzuphologo"><br>
        <p class="mylove">my love / mon amour / il mio amore / mi amore</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I've got some animation effect, already behind the logo here:

http://zupho.bootstrap.gridhosted.co.uk/

But as you can see, the hover effect is in a square shape - as opposed to wrapping around the pentagon logo - how do I get it to wrap around please?

Comment: The image is square therefore the border effect with be square as well. You may have to create a smaller, round element that hosts that effect and then absolutely position the square image over it. I would offer more help but you haven't provided any code. You should read these: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

I use for shadow SVG-hexagon with `filter: blur()` and property `fill` for colorize.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: black;
}

div {
  position: relative;
}

img,
svg {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

svg {
  width: 168px;
  height: 196px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(30deg);
  animation: glow 1.5s linear infinite alternate;
  filter: blur(0px);
  z-index: -10;
  fill: #aaa;
  transition: .2s;
}

@keyframes glow {
  from,
  to {
    filter: blur(0px);
  }
  50% {
    filter: blur(80px);
  }
}

img:hover+svg {
  fill: rgba(244, 66, 232, 1);
}


}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://zupho.bootstrap.gridhosted.co.uk/assets/img/logo.png">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M18 2l6 10.5-6 10.5h-12l-6-10.5 6-10.5z"/></svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Andrey that looks great, but no idea how to apply that - my html is this:

Comment: sorry, but I already did more than necessary. I showed you the principle of solving the problem.

Comment: no idea mate - sorry not helpful to me. but thanks for your efforts